# How can i set Actions for images in the android?

Tags: android, image, onclicklistener

in my application i have one bag-round image with 5 icons how can i put on-click actions for individual icons in the android in my case 5 icons is place in the one image and that image used as bag-round image in my app.

Please help me thanks in Advance......

Comment: first you have to divide  bag-round image in to five part, after this 5 image set in linear layout as per your original image, then set 5 image view and set onsetOnClickListener event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ImageButton and listen its on click method:

```
imgB =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.Image_Button_ID);
imgB.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    // write your code here
});
```

Or if you want to specify the method in the xml:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/Image_Button_ID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blah"
    android:onClick="cutsom_onclick_method" />
```

Hopefully I am not misunderstanding, it is not very clear to me what you need.

OnTouchListener will give you the location of the click which you can use to determine where you have clicked.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                int x = (int) e.getX();
                int y = (int) e.getY();
            }
            // then do some calculation with x and y and where they are
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The other way is to use five ImageButtons and five different images

Comment: but in my case 5 images is in one baground image how can i put action for each icon seprate?

Comment: in my baground image having 5 icons icon1 icon2 icon3 icon4 icon5 i want put onclick actions for each one with different activity ?

Comment: In that case perhaps you need OnTouch if you can determine the position of the icons. See my editted post

Comment: in my case there is no chance to put 5 image buttons my baground having 5 images in one single image ?

Comment: at that situation quality of the image is lost ? is there another alternative to do this ?